# Google Sites web app to parse free text and open a URL

Tags: url, google-apps-script

Very new to this, but struggling to join the dots.

I want a free text box on my Google Site that is used to open files I have in my Drive. So for example:

User enters 'password': 1su-MdTjsT2sqQ0LZbtpD_4pGjh4U7PlKfwy06kTKq4p4
And the following URL is opened: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1su-MdTjsT2sqQ0LZbtpD_4pGjh4U7PlKfwy06kTKq4p4

The 'password' is something I provide via email.The target URL is a Drive document which I've made available via the url link.

The motivation here is to force all users to go to a common home page first (irrespective of the file I'm sharing).

Apologies again, a bit of advice would go far to help me to crystallise my thoughts around this.

Comment: Are you trying to open a URL using Appscript?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any code to show we can't help you here.
Nevertheless I belive the solution is not in appscript here. If you are doing a google site then you can include a "html box" where you can build your form. It's only client code here so just HTML and JS will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Harold. Yep, after a bit more playing I'm realising that deficiency is my knowledge of how to code a JS script to parse "1su-MdTjsT2sqQ0LZbtpD_4pGjh4U7PlKfwy06kTKq4p4" with " https://drive.google.com/open?id=" to open a new tab with that URL. So I'm still stuck... though am more in the territory of "known unknowns"